# Save jointjs diagram drawn on paper, which can be rendered to paper to edit

Tags: svg, jointjs

Working on jointjs diagrams on paper.
I am able to download the diagram drawn on a paper using following code:

```
var svgDoc = paper.svg;
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var svgString = serializer.serializeToString(svgDoc);
```

Now I want to save this svg on server, which can be rendered again to paper so that I can edit it and save again.

Is it possible in jointjs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope. SVG import is not possible in JointJS. The way you should do it is to export the diagram into JSON and than import it back:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(graph);
// send the json to the server, store to DB or whatever....

// ... later on...

// load back the json to the diagram:
graph.fromJSON(JSON.parse(json))
```

See http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Graph:toJSON

Comment: while downloading this svg the css class .connection-wrap is not showing effect. The link area is getting filled by black color. Am I missing something??